# Is it appropriate to use minus-plus with inequalities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it appropriate to use $\mp$ with inequalities instead of using it with a $\pm$ , like in the following examples?

$$\mp\ 2\leq 2\implies -2<2\ ,\ 2=2\\ \text{or}\\
x+4\ge\mp\ (x+4)\implies x+4>-(x+4)\ ,\ x+4=x+4$$

Comment: When it is appropriate to use $\pm$ then it is appropriate to write $\mp$, because it is the same. But why would you do that, and not write $-2\leq 2$, or $-2\leq x\leq 2$ like everybody else? I have never seen this notation in the context of inequalities and I would not recommand you to do it.

Comment: The question has been edited for clarity.

Comment: To me, the only real reason to use $\mp$ is in an expression where $\pm$ already occurs, to indicate that the two signs must always be opposite; for example, we could write $1-(x\pm y)^2 = 1-x^2\mp 2xy-y^2$. I wouldn't use either $\mp$ or $\pm$ in the examples you gave; to me that's placing a higher value on using fewer characters (or using a higher ratio of math to words) than on actual clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, $\mp$ signs are used sparingly in mathematics. Here is an example of when it would be appropriate to use this symbol:
$$
\cos (\alpha \pm \beta) = \cos \alpha \cos \beta \mp \sin \alpha \sin \beta \, .
$$
The rationale behind using it here is that when you are *adding* $\alpha$ and $\beta$ on the LHS, you are  *subtracting* $\cos \alpha \cos \beta$ and $\sin \alpha \sin \beta$ on the RHS. But this 'add-subtract' guideline is, well, just a guideline. If $x=\pm 5$, then you would be forgiven for writing $-x = \pm 5$ rather than $-x = \mp 5$. I would especially warn about using this symbol when solving inequalities, as the mental effort of keeping track of the 'flips' between $\pm$ and $\mp$ might make you more prone to error.

Overall, mathematical notation is not set in stone—it's about clear communication. Sometimes being pedantic about whether you should use $\pm$ or $\mp$ can do more harm than good.